# Joomla 4 - 'Edit My Profile' Form - create custom generic form

Tags: joomla-4.x, php7

I have created a custom (com_users/profile/edit.php). I have created a custom form that I would like to use - however, when I save the form - the value do not store in the db and the page does not successfully refresh. This only happens when the password_reset_required for the user =1...otherwise the page saves/refreshes as it should. I know that it locks the user to this page if a password reset is required.

Is there something that I am missing that will allow my custom form to save for this use case?